# Unix - Associate local IP to pts?

Tags: unix, ip, pts

3 ppl (A B C) are connected to a local server (S1) through SSH (putty, or Unix console), with the same username (foobar). Is there a way to associate their own IP to the pts they create ?

For example, a command witch display that :

```
S1:/root# ls -l /dev/pts
crw------- 1 foobar   tty  136, 0 16 apr 10:34 0 <-> 192.168.0.A
crw------- 1 foobar   tty  136, 2 16 apr 10:22 2 <-> 192.168.0.B
crw------- 1 foobar   tty  136, 3 16 apr 09:26 3 <-> 192.168.0.A
crw------- 1 foobar   tty  136, 5 16 apr 09:26 5 <-> 192.168.0.C
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"who" command shows you the association between pts-s and hostnames (or ip-s if there is no hostname). You can change the hostnames to IP using 'host' command (if this is a requirement for you).

Comment: I think also "finger" command provides the information you were looking for, but in the short format might not show the full host name (but I think it does in the long format "finger -l")

Comment: Well, I didn't know finger, and yes, `finger -l` seems to give me informations I need too ! ;) Thx